# Google Analytics 4 - в "Центр анализа" не приходят данные по специальным параметрам

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

В Менеджере тегов создано событие "add_to_cart". У него есть несколько специальных параметров, один из них "model".

В Google Аналитику данное событие приходит, и данный параметр тоже, это видно в разделе "События".

[image: скрин1]

Но при просмотре отчета в "Центре анализа" видно, что данные по параметру "model" не приходят.

[image: скрин2]

Другой специальный параметр "page" отображает данные.

[image: скрин3]

Разница между ними только в переменной, из которой получают данные. "page" получает данные из переменной {{Page URL}}, а "model" из {{Click ID}}.

[image: скрин4]

Что сделать, чтобы данные по параметру "model" пришли в "Центр анализа"?

Comment: в техподдержку?

Comment: Для обычных пользователей нет поддержки.

"Поддержка доступна только партнерам по продажам и клиентам, которые приобрели рекламные услуги Google Платформы для маркетинга или доступ к Аналитике 360 напрямую у Google."